# Does a storm sorcerer's Tempestuous Magic stack with the Levitate spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, sorcerer, stacking

On the back of [What happens when a Storm sorcerer uses Tempestuous Magic to fly 10 feet straight up?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138081/what-happens-when-a-storm-sorcerer-uses-tempestuous-magic-to-fly-10-feet-straigh/138082#138082) if a Storm Sorcerer uses *Tempestuous Magic* to move vertically 10' and then casts *Levitate* on themselves for a vertical 20' would they then remain 30' off the ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, you will *levitate*

[Tempestuous Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#StormSorcery) (XGtE, 52) states (my emphasis):

> Starting at 1st level, you can use a bonus action on your turn to cause whirling gusts of elemental air to briefly surround you, **immediately before or after you cast a spell** of 1st level or higher.

In the case you describe, you are triggering the whirling gusts immediately before you cast *[levitate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/levitate)* (PHB, 255). This will allow you to rise up 10' and then have the spell increase your height by up to 20'.

Comment: A willing creature doesn't have to make a saving throw against *levitate* does it?

Comment: @Someone_Evil I"m not actually sure. The line does read "An unwilling creature that succeeds on a Constitution saving throw is unaffected." Which implies that a willing creature can be willing, but it doesn't actually say it. However, it's loose enough that I think I can remove that bit about failure.

Comment: Side note: technically, you can use the 10' fly after you *Levitate* as well.